# Codeigniter Notification System URL Structure

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, notifications

First I apologize for my english.

I am trying to develop a facebook-like notification system with Codeigniter. I know it's much better technology, but it's not about using them right now.

The problem I'm experiencing is related to the url structure.
I assume that each notification is a url that needs to go.

**Scenario - 1**
URL structure that sends directly to relevant content.

Notification Link:
https://www.example.com/event/detail/123/?notif_id=456&notif_type=event

When the notification link is this way, I need to go to the activity controls and mark it as read in the detail function. Or I need to create a main controller such as "my_controller" and check if there is data coming with get each page first, then if it exists and matches the session user id, I have to mark it as read.

**Scenario - 2**

Notification Link:
https://www.example.com/notification/123/

(Assuming that each notification is a url that should go)

When the notification link is this way, I need to go to the notification controls, mark it as read in the read function, and then redirect to the relevant link.

As a result, the second scenario makes more sense when I think about it. Because in many places I do it all in one place instead of marking it as read separately. But the examples I see on the internet are usually in the first scenario.

Which way do you think will be healthier and more performant? Which way should I follow?

Comment: Too broad. Please read stacks mvce guideline.